# http retry for Request Timeout (408)

Tags: http, go, retrypolicy, request-timed-out, http-status-code-408

Using hashicorp `go-retryablehttp` library (https://github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp)

It retries automatically for all `5xx` code:

> retryablehttp performs automatic retries under certain conditions. Mainly, if an error is returned by the client (connection errors, etc.), or if a 500-range response code is received (except 501), then a retry is invoked after a wait period. Otherwise, the response is returned and left to the caller to interpret.

Is that possible it retries on `Request Timeout`, e.g. on `408` http status code just ootb?
or I should build some custom wrappers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement your own retry policy and pass it to the Client.CheckRetry field.

Doc ref:

- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp?utm_source=godoc#Client
- https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp?utm_source=godoc#DefaultRetryPolicy

Code ref:

- https://github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp/blob/02c1586c8f14be23e7eeb522f1094afbabf45e93/client.go#L401
- https://github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp/blob/02c1586c8f14be23e7eeb522f1094afbabf45e93/client.go#L424

The code might look like something similar to

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp"
)

func main() {

    retryClient := retryablehttp.NewClient()
    retryClient.RetryMax = 10
    retryClient.CheckRetry = func(ctx context.Context, resp *http.Response, err error) (bool, error) {
        ok, e := retryablehttp.DefaultRetryPolicy(ctx, resp, err)
        if !ok && resp.StatusCode == http.StatusRequestTimeout {
            return true, nil 
            // return true for a retry, 
            // if e is nil,
            // you might want to populate that error 
            // to propagate it.
            // see https://github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp/blob/02c1586c8f14be23e7eeb522f1094afbabf45e93/client.go#L673
        }
        return ok, e
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As source code specify in line 354 in file [client.go](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp/blob/master/client.go), you can configure the `CheckRetry` function to retry in any custom scenario.

```
    // CheckRetry specifies the policy for handling retries, and is called
    // after each request. The default policy is DefaultRetryPolicy.
    CheckRetry CheckRetry
```

Only you need to do is write a function in below type and configure the `retryablehttp.Client.CheckRetry` with that custom implementation.

```
type CheckRetry func(ctx context.Context, resp *http.Response, err error) (bool, error)
```